# Problema al insertar datos en tabla Mysql con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hola amigos tengo un problema y es que no logro insertar datos en una tabla de mysql, si bien ya utilicé el mismo código en otro proyecto, no entiendo donde está el error porque justamente no me tira ningun error al enviar el formulario.
hace varios días que vengo trabado con esto y seguro es alguna cosa tonta que no me estoy dando cuenta...

Este es mi config.php.

```
<?php 


// --------------- CONEXION A LA BD ---------------

$db = 'merlo_turismo';
$usuario = 'root';
$passw = '';

try { $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db;charset=utf8", $usuario, $passw);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

// ------------ FIN CONEXION A LA BD ---------------

 ?>
```

Y este es el codigo:

```
    require 'config.php';

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $user = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['reg_usuario']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email = $_POST['reg_email'];
        $password = $_POST['reg_pass'];
        $password2 = $_POST ['reg_pass2'];

        $errores = '';

        if (empty($user) or empty($password) or empty($email) or empty($password2)) {
            $errores .= '<li>Por favor rellena todos los datos correctamente</li>';
        } else {

            $statement = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE nombre_usuario = :usuario LIMIT 1');
            $statement->execute(array(':usuario'=> $user));
            $resultado = $statement->fetch();

            if ($resultado != false) {
                # Esto significaría que ya existe el usuario
                $errores .= '<li>Ese nombre de usuario ya existe</li>';
            }

            $password = hash('sha512', $password);
            $password2 = hash('sha512', $password2);

            if ( $password != $password2) {
                # Si las contraseñas son diferentes:
                $errores .= '<li>Las contraseñas no son iguales</li>';
            }

        }

        if ($errores == '' && $_POST['submit'])  {
            # esto significaria que no hay errores

            $statement2 = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO users (nombre_usuario,email,pass) VALUES (NULL, :usuario, :email, :pass)');
            $statement2->execute(array(
                ':usuario' => $user,
                ':email' => $email,
                ':pass'=> $password
                ));

            var_dump($statement2);

            // header('Location: login.php');
        }
    }

require 'views/registro.view.php';
 ?>
```

y este es el formulario desde donde envío los datos:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" class="form-contacto">
    <p>Los campos marcados con un <span class="text-warning">*</span> son necesarios</p>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="reg_usuario">Por favor ingresa tu nombre</label>
        <input id="reg_usuario" name="reg_usuario" type="text" placeholder="Nombre de usuario *" class="form-control" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="reg_email">Ingresa tu E-mail</label>
        <input id="reg_email" name="reg_email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail *" class="form-control" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label for="reg_pass">Ingresa una contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" name="reg_pass" id="reg_pass" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label for="reg_pass2">Ingresa tu contraseña nuevamente</label>
        <input type="password" name="reg_pass2" id="reg_pass2" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <?php if (!empty($errores)): ?>  <!-- Si la variable errores no está vacía significa que si hay errores-->
        <div class="alert error">
            <?php echo $errores; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Crear una cuenta">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a insertar esa consulta directamente en MySQL, si hay algun error te lo devolverá, desde mi punto de vista lo de :usuario no me gusta mucho, quizas está ahí el error

Comment: Gracias por contestar, ya probé lo de insertar la consulta sin poner los de :usuario de esta forma:  INSERT INTO users (nombre_usuario,email,pass) VALUES ($user, $email, $password); y tampoco funciona. Cabe destacar que la primer consulta, el SELECT funciona correctamente, lo unico que falla es al hacer el INSERT. No me tira ningun error, es bastante raro